# Create a dictionary from two dictionaries using the key from one with the value of the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'a':'python','b':'java','c':'c++','d':'js',........}
d2 = {'1':'a','2':'b','4':'d','3':'c',........}
```

I need to make new dictionary using both, second dict value should be key of new dict and first dict values should be value of new dict dict, like:

```
result  = {'1':'python','2':'java','3':'c++','4':'js',........}
```

I try to do it like this :

```
d2_rev = {j:i for i,j in d2.items()}
result = {i:d2_rev[i] for i,j in d2_rev }
```

I am getting correct output accept I have very large dictionaries and execution is taking more time. Is there anything I can do to improve the speed of this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you're creating an additional (switched) dictionary, you could just use:

```
result = {i: d1[j] for i, j in d2.items()}
```

and cut down memory and speed by not creating the additional `dict`. The value of the one dict is the key in the other, just get it directly.

Other than that; I don't think, in Python alone, you'd be able to get better results.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `dict.get(key)` over `dict[key]` in case `key` is not present in your `d1` dict. In that case `dict.get(key)` will return `None`. Then you can store the result using *dict comprehension* as mentioned in *[Jim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40654144/2063361)*. Hence your expression should be:

```
result = {i: d1.get(j) for i, j in d2.items()}
```

Sample example:

```
>>> d1 = {'a':'python','b':'java','c':'c++'}
>>> d2 = {'1':'a','2':'b','4':'d'}
#                              ^ 'd' key is not present in d1
>>> result = {i: d1.get(j) for i, j in d2.items()}
>>> result
{'1': 'python', '2': 'java', '4': None}
#                             ^ result holds `None` value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = {'a':'python','b':'java','c':'c++','d':'js',........}
d2 = {'1':'a','2':'b','4':'d','3':'c',........}
result = {}
for k in d2:
    result[k] = d1[d2[k]]


>>> result
{'1':'python','2':'java','4':'js','3':'c++',........}
```